# Passing Arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app and I need to send data in an array from one view controller to another.  I'm pulling a String from a label into a variable and appending it into the array.

```
var time:String = timeLabel.text!
timeArray.append(time)
print("add data")
```

I then have a `prepareForSegue` function where I want to pass data from `firstViewController` to `SecondViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    nvc.timeArray2 = timeArray
}
```

In my secondViewController, I have all of the necessary functions for a `tableView`, but my tableView never populates with any data, as the `timeArray2` is empty and will either result in a crash or in an empty `tableView`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    scrambleTimeTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return timeArray2.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = scrambleTimeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = timeArray2[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    
    print("Populate tableview")
    
    return cell
}
```

Anything I'm missing?

EDIT:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    
    let cell = scrambleTimeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = timeArray2[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    
    print("Populate tableview")
    
    return cell
}
```

I get a crash on `cell.textLabel?.text = timeArray2[indexPath.row]` because the array in the secondViewController is empty. The error reads:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

The output says:

> empty
>
> []
>
> fatal error: Index out of range
>
> (lldb)

I had it print the array and if it was full/empty, along with if the array was filling in the firstViewController, which looks like this:

> add data
>
> ["01.12"]
>
> add data
>
> ["01.12", "01.48"]

So I know that the 1st array is filling, and its not able to send any data to the 2nd controller.

Comment: did you set `tableView delegate` and `dataSource`?

Comment: Do you initialise the array: timeArray = [String]() before you use it?

Comment: Yes to both, my timeArray is initialized and I have the delegate and dataSource

Comment: Try move scrambleTimeTableView.reloadData() to viewDidAppeare and also add print(timeArray2) to see have you got the data.

Comment: It never prints the data so I assume it never loads the function, but its hard to test anything because the array still loads as empty and causes it to crash

Comment: Whats the crash exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Passing info between view controllers can be tricky, especially when one of them is a tableview.  The timing of the events is kinda counterintuitive.  To avoid problems, you shouldn't assume things load in any particular order.

In your specific case, it's possible `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` is being called before the segue happens (the API doesn't guarantee this *won't* happen, so we need to handle that case).

The fix: first, *never* use force-unwrapped optionals (the ! operator).  Optionals exist for exactly this reason: if something is optional, you need to check if it's valid before you use it -- it's a "hint" that it's possible for the data not to be valid at some point in time.

Second: use a `didSet` in your `timeArray` to trigger your `reloadData()`

Something like this:

```
var timeArray: [MyTimeType] = [] {
   didSet {
      tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Also, your segue function should be more like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
        nvc.timeArray2 = timeArray
    }
}
```

The `destinationViewController` may or may not be the one you expect -- you should always check.

Hope that helps!